# Link to be displayed as imgsrc

Tags: php

I have a code here that outputs a image link like `http://img.domain.com/2515.jpg`

`<?php echo IMG_URL . $code . ".jpg" ?>`

But i want to make it print this entire thing `<img src="http://img.domain.com/2515.jpg" alt="" title="Created by domain.com" />`

How can i format that php string `<?php echo IMG_URL . $code . ".jpg" ?>`

to include that entire img src link?

I am trying to fit it in this html code below

`<li><a class="linkInsert" data-value="<?php echo IMG_URL . $code . ".jpg" ?>">Direct Link (email &amp; IM)</a></li>`

Update:

i figured it out below with just using '

`<li><a class="linkInsert" data-value='<img src="<?php echo IMG_URL . $code ?>.jpg" alt="">'>HTML Image (websites / blogs)</a></li>`

Comment: Basically instead of just printing the link, i want it to print as the  link which displays an image

Comment: What don't you like about `<img src="<?php echo $whatever; ?>">`?

Comment: You can also use a backslash to escape quotes inside a string: `"<img src=\"".IMG_URL.$code.".jpg\">"`. The quotes with a backslash before them will be escaped so PHP will still see them as part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can be embedded inside HTML:

```
<img src="<?php echo IMG_URL . $code ?>.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: One thing is i have it embedded in two more " " outside and it messes it up

Comment: I am displaying it as `          <li><a class="linkInsert" data-value="<?php echo IMG_URL . $code . ".jpg" ?>">Direct Link (email &amp; IM)</a></li>
`

Comment: Where does the IMG element come into it then? `data-value` is an attribute and has nothing to do with an image element

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php echo '<img src="'.IMG_URL.$code.'.jpg" alt="" title="Created by domain.com" />' ;?>
```

You just have to use single quotes and double quotes alternatively.